# How to create a Hyperlink inside Visual Studio code, which when clicked will bring me to the linked part inside the same file

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to create a Hyperlink inside Visual Studio code, which when clicked will bring me to that linked part (other portion) inside the same file?

Example:

Page 1 -> when clicked will bring me to the first page.

Page 2 -> when clicked will bring me to the second page.

Page 3 -> when clicked will bring me to the third page.

.

Thanks, Faye

Comment: You might get an answer more quickly on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) which is where you’ll find many developers hanging out.

Comment: Why not use book marks?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to actually create hyperlinks but what you're describing is bookmarks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wffxsy0.aspx

You can put bookmarks (makers) on a line of code and grim that window which lists all bookmarks click on any top jump to that line of that file.

There is also MarkedStrings which may give you what you want... https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8223

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to (bookmarks). Ok thanks, I will refer to your given website. Thanks..

Comment: I've tried Bookmarks, and realized it's not what I want. I want something like hyperlinks, with which I can attached to a single word, that when clicked, will jump to a specific location inside the document that it is linked to..